# How do I take a variable from my python file and display it as a kivyMD text field?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have started creating an application using KivyMD. I am at a point in which I want to display the users name on my screen as a KivyMD label. All the solution I have found online do not suit my use case.

Below is a section of my python file:

```py
    def RecordCheck(self, passwords, emails):
        CheckPassword = emails.text
        CheckEmail = passwords.text
        conn = sqlite3.connect('UserRecords.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?", (CheckEmail, CheckPassword))
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        name = "EXAMPLENAME"

        if result:
            print("match")
##When this is executed I want the label from my kv file to say Welcome, name
            self.root.current = "home"
        else:
            print("no match")
            print("clicked")
```

Below is a section of my KV file:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    Screen:
        MDLabel:
            id: "welcome_label"
## text which should say "Welcome, name"
            text: "Welcome, USER NAME"
            hallign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 0.95}
            font_size: 30
            font_style: "H5"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if more information is required.